# adding rows from the same table that match a criteria in a inner join result

Tags: mysql, join

I'm new to programming.

This is assignment work..... AND this is also my first ever SO post !!

Hello world! :)

I've hit a wall trying to use a join/union or ("other" method??) on the results of an inner join query with additional rows from the same table (based on a matching secondary ID).

I'm creating a view with the output.

I have a member table as m

Each member is denoted as part of a family group with family_ID

Each family has a primary contact (primaryContact_ID) person who pays membership fees. membership payments for each primarycontact_ID are in a membershippayment table as mp.

I wish to select all members who are considered paid in a certain year. Note: this means that where the family primary contact has paid, other family members are therefore considered paid / current.

So first I can select paid primary contacts easily. using:

```
SELECT  m.memberNumber, m.firstName, m.lastName, m.family_ID , mp.yearCurrentTo
FROM member m
INNER JOIN membershippayment mp
on m.primaryContact_ID = mp.primaryContact_ID
WHERE mp.yearCurrentTo = 2015
```

The output is

```
memberNumber | firstName | lastName | family_ID | yearCurrentTo 
    6        |   ted     |   smith  |    2      |       2015
```

But Ted has 3 other family members ( also in the members table m) as denoted by family_ID = "2"

How do I (select or join or union or "Other") additional family members with m.family_ID as Ted ?

The family_id value will be dynamic and have 1 or more values, depending on the inner join result set.

i have tried adding an inner join to the original member table using a second alias :

```
 SELECT  m.memberNumber, m.firstName, m.lastName, m.family_ID, mp.yearCurrentTo
FROM member m
INNER JOIN membershippayment mp
on m.primaryContact_ID = mp.primaryContact_ID
INNER JOIN member m2
on m2.family_ID = m.family_ID
WHERE mp.yearCurrentTo = 2015
```

But all I get is Teds details repeated 3 more times.

```
    memberNumber | firstName | lastName | family_ID | yearCurrentTo 
        6        |   ted     |   smith  |    2      |       2015
        6        |   ted     |   smith  |    2      |       2015
        6        |   ted     |   smith  |    2      |       2015
        6        |   ted     |   smith  |    2      |       2015
```

it should be each additional family member, of unique memberNumber but matching family_ID

I've also tried a union but get similar repeated rows.

From here i'm stumped.

Can it all be achieved in the same query ?  I'm thinking using nesting . But I get lost attempting this.

or should I use an updateable view and do a separate select and update query.

Thanks !

Comment: try studying about `GROUP BY` and related syntax, it can help you alot.

Comment: thanks @Avidos, will do

Comment: That's the only thing that is missing to your `assignment` code, keep moving forward mate